# MediaRecorder in BroadCast

Tags: android

I want to create small app MediaRecord on smsreciver. when i recive message recording start and stop autometically . My problem is on sms recive recording is start but its never stop on next sms recive and my recorded file is successfully created but there is nothing inside. plz help

```
public class BroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";



    private String recivedKey;

    private MediaRecorder recorder;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());



        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }
                if (messages.length > -1) {

                    if (messages[0].getOriginatingAddress() != null) {



                        if (recivedKey.equals(String.valueOf(record_key))) {

                            // Stop it being passed to the main Messaging

                            abortBroadcast();

                            startRecording();

                            SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            smsMgr.sendTextMessage(formattedNumber, null,
                                    "Recording has been started, to stop recording any time send "
                                            + stop_record_key, null, null);
                        }

                        if (recivedKey.equals(String.valueOf(stop_record_key))) {
                            // Stop it being passed to the main Messaging
                            abortBroadcast();
                            stopRecording();
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

    public void startRecording() {

        System.out.println("STart Recording");

        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.release();
        } else {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());

            try {
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                recorder.release();
            }
        }

    }

    private void stopRecording() {

        System.out.println("Stop Recording");

        try {
            if (null != recorder) {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.reset();
                recorder.release();
                recorder = null;
            }

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String getFilename() {
        File rootsd = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
        if (!rootsd.isDirectory()) {
            rootsd.mkdir();
        }
        File dcim = new File(rootsd+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".3gp");

        return dcim.getAbsolutePath();
    }

}
```

Comment: i am trying to implement using following link   http://playingwithandroid.blogspot.ca/2012/08/how-to-record-voice-call-in-android.html   but no luck

Comment: silly mistake solved remove finally block